# socket.io, vTiger, and csrf-magic.js. CORS issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, vtiger, vtigercrm

I'm attempting to create and add a `socket.io` module to my `vTiger 7.0` so that I can update fields in real-time to multiple users.

We are have issues with users changing fields that should be locked while our quality control is attempting to check the record. This is causes things to get approved that should not. `Node.js` with `vTiger` will be awesome add-on.

The only problem is that `vTiger` uses `csrf-magic.js` to create a `token` that need to be included in the `header` to allow `CORS`

I have the middleware setup in my `node` project to allow my `vtiger` to make a request

`vTiger` is on `vtiger.example.com`

The `node` server is on node`.example.com:3010`

```
//server code node.example.com:3010
const fs = require("fs");
const config = require("./core/config").config();
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.cert),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(config.ca),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
};

const app = require("express")();
const server = require("https").Server(options, app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
// Need to send io to socket module

module.exports = io;
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var allowedOrigins = [
        "https://node.example.com",
        "https://vtiger.example.com"
    ];
    var origin = req.headers.origin;
        if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    }

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    
    return next();
});

io.sockets.on("connection", require("./sockets/socket.js"));

const qc = require('./models/qc_model');
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.json({message: 'No Access'});
})

qc.pullLeadInfo(13622196, 10730, (data) => {
    console.log(data.lead.lsloa_ver_by);
});
    




//Start the server
server.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log("server listening on port: " + config.port);
});
```

```
\\client side vtiger.example.com
var socket = io.connect('https://node.example.com:3010');
```

I get this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://node.example.com:3010/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NmEEc_r' from origin 'https://vtiger.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
csrf-magic.js:41 GET https://node.example.com:3010/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NmEEc_r net::ERR_FAILED
```

I cannot find any good documentation dealing with this issue. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the information here

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3929

```js
// Server

io.engine.on("headers", (headers) => {
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network"] = true;
});
```

```js
// Client

const socket = io({
  extraHeaders: {
    "Access-Control-Request-Private-Network": true
  }
});
```